# WordPress Website is generating random Advertisements in new tab

Tags: php, wordpress, security, cookies, header

I am facing a problem with my website https://konhost.com, whenever I open my website in a new tab or new window and click on it for the first time then it opens a new window with an advertisement.

I have also scaned my website with virustotal.com and this comes out:

> accept-ranges: bytes
>  age: 0
>  cache-control: no-store, no-cache,
>   must-revalidate
>  connection: keep-alive
>  content-type:
>   text/html; charset=UTF-8
>  date: Fri, 08 Sep 2017 19:25:49 GMT
>   expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>  pragma: no-cache
>   set-cookie: PHPSESSID=0t51snf947vas0a2ifsq8v4590; path=/
>   transfer-encoding: chunked
>  vary: Accept-Encoding
>  x-cache:
>   MISS
>  x-varnish: 184009294

But I am still not sure what to do and how to fix this problem. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: which hosting provider you are using ? are you using any free hosting ?

Comment: Is this the add traffic your seeing? http://update2new.apptrafficupdates.pw./.....

Comment: This doesn't look like a WordPress site to me.

Comment: I am not using any free hosting.